# Dhtmlxgantt how can i change the height of the Task Bars?

Tags: database, frameworks, font-size

Hello i work with the Framework Dhtmlxgantt. And i would like to change the height of the Task Bars. They are to big for me and i would like to have id smaller. Is this possible? Because i search alot and i dont find anything about that. And i have another Problem. I have in my Database some Projects and a part of them has in the Titel html tags and the other not. The result is in the Gantt chart is the Titel field in diffrent font size what looks stupid. So is there a way to change that before id rendert on the Gantt chart or have i to change all Titel's in the Database? I hope some of you can help me. Greece

Answer (score 0):

try this to set height

```
gantt.config.row_height = 36;
gantt.config.task_height = 20; 
gantt.config.scale_height = 50;
```

To set task text use templates

```
gantt.templates.task_text=function(start, end, task) {
    return "anything you want";
};
```

You can return task.text or task.id or "(" + task.text + " id = " + task.id + ")"

It seems to be easy )